# Update a Listview column when checkbox is checked

Tags: wpf, listview, checkbox, checked

I want to update a Column in a listview when the checkbox is checked in the same row. Checkbox is a part of a row.

View:

Check Box:

```
<CheckBox Tag="{Binding ID}" Checked="chbAccount_checked" Unchecked="chbAccount_Unchecked"/>
```

Text block in the column that needed to be updated:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyColumnValue }" />
```

Code Behind:

```
private void chbAccount_checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chb = sender as CheckBox;
    int Id= Convert.ToInt16(chb.Tag);
    ViewModel.UpdateColumnValue(Id);
    myListView.ItemsSource = ViewModel.Accounts;
    this.myListView.UpdateLayout();              
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public void UpdateColumnValue(int Id)
{
    foreach(var a in Accounts)
    {
        if(a.ID == Id)
        {
            a.MyColumnValue = "Yes";
        }
    }
}
```

Account list is updating but the list view doesn't show the Modified values in the column. I have tried refreshing listview by listview.item.refresh(). Didn't work.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: You are already using Bindings. Why not updating the bound property? If you implement INotifyPropertyChanged you just have to update you MyColumnValue property. That's one advantage of the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with INotifyPropertyChanged . Went through some tutorials. I think I can handle this now. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: And "yes" it is working :) :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you bind the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` to a `bool` source property of your view model and handle the logic of setting the `MyColumnValue` property in the view model class:

```
<CheckBox Tag="{Binding ID}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

---

```
private bool _icChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return _icChecked; ; }
    set { _icChecked; = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); UpdateColumnValue(Convert.ToInt32(ID)); }
}
```

Make sure that the view model class implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface correctly.

Comment: I used INotifyPropertyChanged and it works. Thank you..! :)